# Blocking a specific javascript from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, block, greasemonkey

I am writing a greasemonkey script in Firefox/Chrome to map websites (like a web-crawler), and one website is giving me a headache because many of it's pages contain this

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

Now, the problem is that this script takes ages to load, and actually is not in use anymore. I don't have access to the page code, so I can't even remove that line.
Is there a way to prevent my browser (Firefox and/or Chrome) from even loading this?

I've tried using the browsers' built in JavaScript blacklist, but then it blocks all the scripts on that page, which is not what I want...

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please explain how you are loading these pages?  In an iframe in the browser?  When you said it was like a web-crawler, I assumed you had a server process that was loading a web page (which wouldn't normally execute scripts anyway).

Comment: I'm doing it with a greasemonkey script on Firefox/Chrome

Comment: This is a perfect use case for the Adblock extension (set a custom rule to block that script).